# pyopenms: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python

I can import pyopenms and the code runs well in spyder. But when I run the same script in Anaconda Prompt, it gives:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Scripts\Python\GUI\test\LipidAnaGUI - Copy.py", line 23, in module import pyopenms

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopenms_*init*_.py", line 75, in module raise e

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopenms_*init*_.py", line 45, in module

> > from .all_modules import *

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopenms\all_modules.py", line 1, in module

> > from .pyopenms_1 import *

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Then I checked the all_modules.py file:

```
from .pyopenms_1 import *
from .pyopenms_2 import *
from .pyopenms_3 import *
from .pyopenms_4 import *
from .pyopenms_5 import *
from .pyopenms_6 import *
from .pyopenms_7 import *
from .pyopenms_8 import *
```

Under the same folder, there are pyopenms_1.cpp and pyopenms_1.cp37-win_amd64.pyd files, but not pyopenms_1.py. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved by copying all `Qt5***.dll` files from

```
Anaconda3\pkgs\qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0\Library\bin
```

to this folder:

```
Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyopenms
```

Comment: I tried my solution once more, and found I need to replace all the orginal Qt5*.DLL in the pyopenms, then it will work. If just add the missing Qt5*.DLL, the error is still there. I am not sure if this will help, but you can try it.

Comment: Also, it seems that if I import pyopenms after `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, it won't work.

Comment: @GoldenYoyo Moving `matplotlib` worked for me too, that should be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @GoldenYoyo I rejected the suggested edit for this one, since original author's answer isn't about changing order of import; I suggest you editing the question and add it, or add it as independent answer!

Answer (score 1):

***For IDE users only:***

PyOpenMs loads Qt even when no GUI is being used.
And if another Qt is loaded *before* PyOpenMs, then this causes it to fail.

GoldenYoyo's comment above, suggests moving your own imports that load Qt (such as `matplotlib`) to before PyOpenMs.
However, IDEs may pre-load the Qt libraries to allow advanced debugging.
This feature needs to be disabled in order to load PyOpenMs in an IDE.

In **PyCharm**/**IntelliJ** this is:

- File | Settings | Build execution and deployment | Python debugger | PyQtCompatible = Unchecked

[image: Settings]