# DLL (.pyd) load failed after a C++ compilation involving pybind11

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, g++, pybind11

I run the following Windows cmd:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -O3  -Wall -L C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.9.7-h6244533_1\libs -shared -std=c++11 -D MS_WIN64 -fPIC -I C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Include -I C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybind11\include MainFile.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp file4.cpp file5.cpp -o MainFile.cp39-win_amd64.pyd -l python39
```

Then I got the expected .pyd library file. However, while running (on PyCharm) the Python main file that imports another Python file that includes `import MainFile`, I always got the error `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing MainFile: The specified procedure could not be found.`

PS:

1. Working on Windows 10, Anconda3, PyCharm 2023.1.1 (Community Edition)
2. Checking dependencies (of the .pyd output file) using https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies looks fine.

Comment: In order to help diagnose this problem, it might be useful to see what you are doing in PYBIND11_MODULE, which is presumably in MainFile.cpp, where you add your module definitions.
Have you seen this issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875548/pyopenms-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found?rq=2)